# Obtain html element by custom attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an element by a custom attribute, the element I want is right below

```
<div id="ember4714" data-test-field-name="Opportunity name">
```

I want to get the element by the `data-test-field-name` attribute when its value equals "Opportunity name", I have to do that because the id always changes value in the panel I'm working on.

How can I get this element by this attribute?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CSS attribute selector:

```js
document.querySelector('[data-test-field-name="Opportunity name"]')
```